# Access jobId to stop download react-native-fs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-fs

How do I access jobId during the download. I have my download function stored in a separate *.js file

```
RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: item.thumb,
      toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${item.id}.jpg`,
      begin: (res) => {
        console.log(res.jobId, item.id);
      },
    })
```

I need to call `stopDownload` function from my UI, so I need to have access to a current `jobId` and I use `Redux` as a state manager but I think I'm not supposed to store `jobId` cause it will cause unnecessary rerenders.

What is the proper way of handling `stopDownload`?